# DeviceCheck - How to handle multiple apps on same device

Tags: ios, iphone, devicecheck

As per DeviceCheck API [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) and [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/702/?time=1444), DeviceCheck bits are per device and per teamID So how can we handle these scenarios?

1. If we have **multiple apps** with trial promotional offer and uploaded
   **under same teamID**, DeviceCheck bits will be same for these apps So
   how can we identify which app has trial period redeemed by user.
2. How can we handle **device sold scenario** as there is not much information in documentation for this.